# How do browsers and crawlers deal with rel="tag"?

Tags: html, browser, attributes, rel

Suppose I have two links on my webpage as:

```
<a href="/balls" rel="tag">The Balls page</a>
<a href="/bats">The Bats page</a>
```

Would browsers or crawlers deal these differently?

Comment: There are *so* many crawlers, and many of them have no source code published nor detailed documentation. Such an open question is too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rel` attributes are SEO elements that, when used properly, can help you provide important information to search engine crawlers. Unfortunately, `rel` attributes are often unused in full potential, which leads to missed opportunities in terms of taking control of a site’s pages.

The basic nature of the `rel` attributes is that they are components of HTML that describe a relationship between pages of a site. These components affect the site’s linking structure. Because links are a huge contributing factor to search engine algorithms, taking advantage of `rel` attributes will only help one’s ranking potential.

The `rel` attributes are placed at the back-end of given site, attached to the links they are providing "instructions" for. That way, when search engines crawl the site, they are able to identify your intentions regarding particular links.

In the case when the anchor tag (`<a>`) has `rel` attribute, the `rel` attribute specifies the relationship **between the current document and the linked document**. They are only used if the `href` attribute is present. The `rel` attribute is simply a tag (keyword) for the current document.

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining.

Answer (score 0):

seems like it .. see [this](http://www.pitstopmedia.com/sem/link-tag-rel-attribute-seo)
good luck trying to find it in use. i took a quick try